# Run python script in Canopy in new python shell

Tags: python, matplotlib, canopy

Unlike other editors (I use TextWrangler and TextMate on the Mac, and Spyder on the PC), Enthought's Canopy runs the Python programs in an interactive python shell. Most of the time this is nice, but sometimes I would like to run the program in a fresh python shell. For example, I am writing a script to collect frames a high-speed camera. If the script does not run all the way to the end (which happens a lot), then the next time I run the script, it crashes the python shell if I am using Canopy (no problems with other editors or running straight from the command line).

So, is there a way that I can have the program run in a new python shell each time, or maybe reset the python shell before running?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can restart the python shell in canopy by selecting Run -> Restart Kernel.

Comment: That's what I am currently doing, but it's a little annoying to have to click "Restart Kernel" and then click again to confirm it each time you want to run a program...